# PHP - Hacer saltar una excepción

Tags: php, php7, php5, excepciones

Tengo esta función que lee ficheros CSV y dentro de ella llamo a un método estático de una clase para hacer una transformación de fechas entre formato americano  y español.
El problema lo tengo que en la clase tengo una excepción pero no me salta, me da el fallo del TRY pero la excepción no me salta.

function readCsvFile($filename) {

```
 $file = fopen($filename, 'r');
 $countLines = 0;

 while (($line = fgetcsv($file,1000,",")) !== FALSE) {
     $data['EventDate'] = DateTimeClass::transformDate($line[11],$filename);
 }

 fclose($file);
```

}

**Clase DateTimeClass**

```
<?php

class DateTimeClass {

    public static function transformDate($datetime,$filename) {

        $pos = strpos($datetime, ".");

        if ($pos != false) {
            $datetime = substr($datetime,0,$pos);
        }

        if ($datetime === null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            $myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime);
            $aux = $myDateTime->format('Y-d-m H:m:s');
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            var_dump($filename);
            var_dump($e);
        }

        return $aux;

    }

}
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *el fallo del `try`*? Agrega a la pregunta el mensaje de error que tienes exactamente. Yo pondría el `return` dentro del bloque `try` y no haría verificación de `null` dado que el bloque `try ... catch` serviría para controlar todo.

Answer (score 1):

Hay varias cosas que deberías tener en cuenta:

En primer lugar, `createFromFormat()` es un método de la clase `DateTime`, no es el constructor, por tanto, no podrás levantar una excepción al llamar al método.

Si lees el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php), en el apartado **Valores devueltos** verás que este método:

> Devuelve una nueva instancia de `DateTime` o `false` en caso de error.

Significa entonces que en lugar de un `try ... catch`, lo que necesitas es controlar el resultado de la llamada al método y, si quieres, desde ahí levantas una excepción.

En segundo lugar, si desde el método de la clase levantas una excepción, la captura de la misma debe ir en la llamada que haces a dicho método. Si lo piensas bien, estás creando una clase como cualquier otra, y los manejos de excepciones se hacen desde fuera de ella, como se hace con todas las clases.

Entendidos ambos puntos, el código quedaría así:

```
class DateTimeClass {

    public static function transformDate($datetime,$filename) {

        /* --- 
           ¿Quizá esto sobra ? */
        $pos = strpos($datetime, ".");

        if ($pos != false) {
            $datetime = substr($datetime,0,$pos);
        }
        /* --- */

        if($myDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', $datetime)) {
            $aux = $myDateTime->format('Y-d-m H:m:s');
            return $aux;
        } else {
           throw new Exception('DateTime::createFromFormat error');
        }
    }
}
```

Y allí donde quieras usar tu clase:

```
try {
      $data['EventDate'] = DateTimeClass::transformDate($line[11],$filename);
      //Trabajar con los datos
} catch (Exception $e) {
      echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

---

### Post-Data

Ignoro cuál sea el propósito de esta clase, pero debo decirte que la implementación de la misma es una involución. ¿Por qué? Porque desde ella devuelves un objeto formateado, y por tanto despojado de todas sus propiedades. Esto no tiene sentido en la POO. Imaginemos que en un determinado contexto necesites lo que devuelve esta clase **pero con otro formato**. Pues ya no tendrás el objeto para formatearlo según ese nuevo formato, viéndote obligado a **crear un nuevo objeto**.

Considera que **los formatos son circunstanciales**, que puedes necesitar diferentes formatos de un mismo objeto. Si devuelves el objeto, no tendrás de crear otro(s) cuando necesites representar ese mismo objeto de formas distintas, según cada circunstancia. Esta es una de las grandes ventajas de la POO, la cual es totalmente ignorada en la implementación de tu clase.